# how to draw grid overlay on Sfmap in UWP Xamarin.From application?

Tags: uwp, grid, overlay, syncfusion

I am working on using Sfmap control in UWP Xamarin.Form application ,i need to draw grid over Sfmap ,how can i do it ?

and each grid cells should be selectable .
i have gone through Sfmap Xamarin.form documentation ,but i did'nt find any thing for grid overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieved by using the Polyline support. Polylines can be drawn using map points to create a grid-like appearance on the map, with lines drawn both horizontally and vertically. I have prepared a sample to achieve your requirement and please find the sample at the below link:
[Download Sample](https://support.syncfusion.com/attachment/download/428542)

Refer to our UG documentation to know more details,
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/maps/shapetype?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml#polyline

Comment: Thanks ,i am unable to dowanload sample given above.   We have requirement like this, user will enter location ,then grid should be displayed over sfmap .and each grid cells should be selectable.  How to achieve this in sfmap Xamarin.form for uwp application?